# window minimize and maximize

Tags: html

I am developing website everything was done and successful  , but my problem is please look attached images , if browser is in maximize position the website looks neat but in minimize situation everything comes closer and text is overlap by another, please suggest me.
[image: maximize]

[image: minimize]

[image: maximize]

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think it is? What does your layout look like?

Comment: Hi., i have tried with position attribute and i have tried with width pixels and % values but no result .

Answer (score 0):

Try using % value of width and height of html elements instead of its pixel values in style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide actual source code, i have to guess. I guess your page layed out using tables. And either  elements have no width property or they have width in percentages like . The black top bar on the first images seems like it made with a table with two columns, second column being align=right.

For table layouts to work, you should set all columns' width to some constant number. Especially first rows' columns' width must be set.